# Create column with values from multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, variables, select, multiple-columns

I want to add a column to a table that includes value from one of two columns, depending on which row contains the value.

For instance,

```
SELECT
  concat("Selecting Col1 or 2", cast("Col1" OR "Col2" as string)) AS relevantinfo,
FROM table
```

I do not know much SQL and I know this query does not work. Is this even possible to do?

```
Col1    Col2
1       
         4
3
4
         5
```

FINAL RESULT

```
Col1    Col2    relevantinfo
1                1
        4        4
3                3
4                4
        5        5
```

Comment: Please, share sample data with an output which you want. as per your current need you can Check coalesce function https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp

Comment: @RajatJaiswal updated with sample data and desired output

Comment: Could you have a value in both `Col1` and `Col2` for the same entry?

Comment: Are the spaces `NULL` values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `COALESCE` function, which will return the first non-null value in the list.

```
SELECT col1, col2, COALESCE(col1, col2) AS col3 
FROM t1;
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05a83/1

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't alter the table structure to add a redundant information that can be retrieved with a simple query.

I would rather use that kind of query with `IFNULL/ISNULL(ColumnName, 'Value to use if the col is null')`:

```
--This will work only if there can't be a value in both column at the same time
--Mysql
SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(Col1,''),IFNULL(Col2,'')) as relevantinfo FROM Table

--Sql Server
SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL(Col1,''),ISNULL(Col2,'')) as relevantinfo FROM Table
```